# Selecting from multiple tables using only SELECT, FROM and WHERE commands?

Tags: sql, relational-database

A SQL / databases question about a hospital from a past exam paper involves two tables:

- A `Patient` table, listing a forename, surname and the ID of the Ward they are currently assigned to.
- A `Ward` table, listing the Wards ID and Name, along with other generic attributes.

The question reads:

"Using the SQL commands `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, write an SQL statement to query the database tables for the forename, surname and medical condition number of all patients in Victoria ward."

So I need to

```
SELECT forename, surname, condition 
FROM patients 
WHERE ward == "Victoria"
```

But this is not possible as the patient does not have a `ward` attribute, only the `wardID`, and for the sake of this question it is assumed that we do not know the ID of the "Victoria" ward.

So I need to select every patient where `Patient.WardID` corresponds to the `Ward.WardID` of "Victoria", without using `INNER JOIN`, which I think, from my reading, would be the normal way to do this.

How do I do this? Thank you

EDIT: I initially produced this, however I do not think it is correct.

```
SELECT patient.forename, patient.surname, patient.condition 
FROM patient, ward 
WHERE patient.WardID = ward.WardID 
  AND Ward.name == "Victoria"
```

Comment: I think your own solution is correct. The `FROM table1 T1, table2 T2 WHERE t1.id_of_something = t2.id` is valid since SQL89 and translated internally to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: There's no sense of limitation in the assignment phrasing in the body of your post. So why did you put "using only" in your title & "without using" in the body? Also: We refer to a SELECT statement/command & to its constituent SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc clauses. But JOIN & comma are neither. Also comma *is* cross join. PS Why did you try that code & why do you think it is not correct? [mcve] PS How is this not exactly like examples you have been given?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a correlated subquery to find the ward name:

```
SELECT
    p.forename
    p.surname,
    p.condition
FROM patient p
WHERE p.WardID = (SELECT WardID FROM ward w
                  WHERE p.WardID = w.WardID AND w.name = 'Victoria');
```

I introduced table aliases into the query to make it more concise and easier to read.  But note that writing your query with an inner join is probably the preferred, and most performant, way to do it.  You should view this question as just a brain teaser to see if your SQL is flexible enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could use  a join:

```
  SELECT
      p.forename
      p.surname,
      p.condition
  FROM patient p
  INNER JOIN ward w ON p.WardID = w.WardID 
    AND w.name = 'Victoria'
```

but for explicit request remember that a join is the equivalent of a where condition. If you don't want join, you could simply use old  (pre 1992) SQL syntax:

```
 SELECT
      p.forename
      p.surname,
      p.condition
  FROM patient p, ward w
  WHERE p.WardID = w.WardID 
    AND w.name = 'Victoria'
```

Comment: "a join is the equivalent of a where condition" does not say what you are trying to say, it is just a bunch of words from it. Also comma denotes cross join, and its use is even called "implicit join".